# Proof-theoretic ordinal and fast-growing hierarchy

Tags: logic, proof-theory

The abstract definition of [Fast-growing hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy) leaves out the definition of the fundamental sequence. It seems the choice of the sequence is crucial in the sense that some choices can break down the whole hierarchy.

In proof-theory fast-growing functions are used as a sort of limit of the growth rate of the functions the theory in hand can prove total.

Is there some default choice of the fundamental sequence used when refering to the fast-growing hierarchy in the context of proof-theory? Is Wainer-hierachy the way to go below $\epsilon_0$ as suggested in Wikipedia? What about above $\epsilon_0$?

Comment: Yes, how to define fundamental sequences is one of the key issues when developing systems of ordinal notation. I recommend you read [MR0881280 (88g:03079)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=881280). Crossley, John N.; Kister, Jane Bridge. [*Natural well-orderings*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02017491). Arch. Math. Logik Grundlag. **26** (1986/87), no. 1-2, 57–76.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Thanks for the reference. I will try to get access to it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue of choosing fundamental sequences for limit ordinals from a given set of ordinal notations is basically solved and can be found, for example, in MR1271290: Buchholz, Wilfried; Cichon, Adam; Weiermann, Andreas:
A uniform approach to fundamental sequences and hierarchies.
Math. Logic Quart. 40 (1994), no. 2, 273–286. 
The issue of choosing fundamental sequences appropriate for the slow growing hierarchy is an active area of research. Andreas Weiermann